# Auto generate serial number in data grid using wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

How to auto generate serial number in datagrid using wpf?`

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sl#" 
                     x:Name="serialnumber" 
                     Binding="{Binding Serial}"/>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a converter with whatever logic is needed to parse the bound value and return a serial number:

```
namespace MyWPFAPP.Converters
{
   public class ConvertToSerialNumber : IValueConverter
   {
       public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
           return $"0000{value}";
       }
       public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
    }
}
```

Then bind using the converter in the page's Xaml:

```
<Window 
 xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyWPFAPP.Converters"
...>
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:ConvertToSerialNumber x:Key="ToSerialNumber" />
</Window.Resources>
...
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Sl#" 
                    x:Name="serialnumber" 
                    Binding="{Binding Serial, Converter={StaticResource ToSerialNumber}}"/>
```

---

Keep in mind that the visible serial number is just that, visible on the screen and does not change the value of, in your example, `serialnumber`.

Frankly it would be better to extend (maybe using the [partial (Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbx7zzdd.aspx) C# paradigm on classes(?)), then on the class housing `serialnumber` and provide a `ToSerialNumber` property to generate such values.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot